# What can we say about the order of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a ∈ G$. If $a^{12}= e$, what can we say about the order
of $a$? What can we say about the order of $G$?

We know that $|a|$ divides $12$, but what can we say about the order of $G$? Would it then be true that $|G|= 12$? Why or why not?

Comment: It may be that $a=1$, and then not much can be said. If you stipulate that $a\neq 1$, then $a$ has order $2,3,4,6$ or $12$, and in each case $|G|$, *if finite*, is divisible by this number. For example, $\Bbb Q^\times$ contains $-1$ and this has order $2$, but $|\Bbb Q|$ is infinite.

Comment: Data: there's only 5 group with 12 elements http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12

Answer (score 0):

*edited*

We know that the order of any subgroup must divide the order of the whole group by Lagrange's Theorem. Since we don't know the order of the element, but we do know it must divide 12, by the reasoning above, we know the order of the element must be $1,2,3,4,6,12$. So the best we can say about the group is NOTHING at all. If we know that $a\ne e$, then we could say $G=2k$ at least. And if we know the order of $a$ is $12$, then we can say the order of the group is $12k$(if the group is finite).

Comment: The question does not assert that $G$ has an element of order 12, but rather that it has an element of order dividing 12.  It could thus have no element with order dividing twelve; or any element of order 3; or any element of order 2.  In fact the statement is trivially satisfied by the identity element in every group.

Comment: I see that, sorry.

Comment: So could we then say that |G| divides |a|?

Comment: I think that is possible for only the trivial group or a prime power cyclic group.

Comment: @H_B After the editing it still isn't correct: the order of the group could be infinite as well, even if $\;ord(a)=12\;$ .

Comment: Sorry, I think I should just stick to asking questions....

Comment: Not at all, @H_B :answering, answering and being wrong, correcting, etc. one can learn a lot. Don't worry about that, and I can tell you this because I've made tons of mistakes here. Just learn and correct and go on.

Answer (score 0):

The order of $a$ is at most $12$, because $a^{12}=e$ and $|a| = \min\{k \ge 1 : a^k=e\}$. In fact, the order of $a$ is a divisor of $12$, because if we use the Euclidean algorithm to divide 12 by $|a|$ we get $$12 = q|a| + r$$ with $0 \le r < |a|$. 
Exponentiating yields $e = a^{12} = a^{q|\,a|+r} = (a^{|\,a|})^qa^r=a^r$; since $|a|$ is the least *positive* exponent killing $a$, we must have $r = 0$. Thus, $12 = q|a|$ so $|a|\in\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

The only thing we can say about the order of $G$ is that if $G$ is finite, then only $|a|$, not necessarily $12$, divides $|G|$. For example, $7 + 14\mathbf{Z}$ has order $2$ in the order-$14$ group $\mathbf{Z}/14\mathbf{Z}$. If $G$ is a group with order $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $6$, or $12$ (and there are $1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 5 = 12$ such groups up to isomorphism) then *every* element $a$ in each of these groups satisfies the equation $a^{12}=e$. The additive group $\mathbf{Z}/24\mathbf{Z}$ contains an element of order $12$ (e.g. $2 + 24\mathbf{Z}$) but has order $24$. The symmetric group $S_4$ also has order $24$, but no elements of order $12$ -- the biggest possible order of a permutation of four things is $4$; note, however, that the least $n$ such that $a^n=e$ for *all* $a$ in $S_4$ is, in fact, $12$ -- this is called the *exponent* of the group.
The infinite group $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$, written additively, has many solutions $\frac{a}{b}$ to $12\big(\frac{a}{b}+\mathbb{Z}\big) = 0+\mathbb{Z}$, like $\frac{1}{3}$ or $\frac{7}{12}$; the precise number is the length of the Farey sequence $\mathscr{F}_{12}$.